# Trouble with QJsonArray

Tags: qt, qtnetwork

In my Console Project I have 4 functions: `Response`, `AddDataToList`, `Request` and `main`.

In `main` function `chars` is a Vector containing characters a-z. `manager`, `doc`, `array` and `list` are variables to be used in `Request` function along with the elements of `chars`. In the first `for` loop a single character (eg. a,b,c,…,z) from `chars` is passed to `Request` and in the following nested `for` loop two characters (eg. aa,ab,ac,…,zz) are passed to `Request`.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QVector<char> chars;
    for (int i = 97; i < 123; i++) chars.push_back((char)i);

    QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    QJsonDocument doc;
    QJsonArray array;
    QVector<QString> list;
    int count = chars.count();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        Request(manager, QString(chars[i]), doc, array, list);
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
            Request(manager, QString("%1%2").arg(chars[i]).arg(chars[j]), doc, array, list);
    }

    qDebug() << "Total: " + QString::number(list.count());
    return a.exec();
}
```

In `Request` those characters are used as `querystring` in the `url` that is passed to `Response` function to get `json array` and each element of `array` is then added to the Vector named `list` in `AddDataToList` function.

```
void Request(QNetworkAccessManager &manager, QString &queryString, 
         QJsonDocument &doc, QJsonArray &array, QVector<QString> &list) 
{
    QUrl url =QString("http://www.icab.org.bd/icabweb/firmCompanyAudited/geJsonAuditedFirm?term=%1").arg(queryString);
    Response(manager.get(QNetworkRequest(url)), doc, array);
    AddDataToList(list, array);
}

void Response(QNetworkReply *reply, QJsonDocument &doc, QJsonArray& array) 
{
    QEventLoop loop;
    QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    loop.exec();
    doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(reply->readAll());
    delete reply;
    array = doc.array();
}

void AddDataToList(QVector<QString> &list, QJsonArray &array) 
{
    int count = array.count();
    for (int n = 0; n < count; n++) list.append(array[n].toString());
}
```

Last line of the `main` writes the number of elements in the `list` and I expected to get same number each time it runs, but the number was:

19793, 19703, 19791, etc.

`reply->error()` always gives `NoError`. 
Where is the problem?

---

**EDIT:**

---

I also have written equivalent code in C# where I had to use `Newtonsoft.Json`'s `DeserializeObject` method in a `try-catch` in order to complete the loop. Result of 5 consecutive test sessions was:

```
Test Session: 0
19793  item found
0 item in error List
====================================================

Test Session: 1
ev : Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
yy : Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
19743  item found
2 item in error List
====================================================

Test Session: 2
cm : Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
jv : Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
nl : Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
19737  item found
3 item in error List
====================================================

Test Session: 3
uk : Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
19743  item found
1 item in error List
====================================================

Test Session: 4
lk : Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
19768  item found
1 item in error List
====================================================
```

May I get somewhat similar error in my `Qt` `Response` function when I call:
`QJsonDocument::fromJson(reply->readAll())` or `doc.array()`?

---

I guess the problem is in `doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(reply->readAll())`. It assigns `<html>` in `doc` in some cases.

Why does it send `<html>` instead of `json`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got curious about your problem and added your code to my test application.

I needed to do one change to get you code compiled with gcc. You were passing temporary object as a query string. Add *const* to `QString &queryString` in Request function. I guess you are using MS compiler which is not as strict with this...

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of 
type ‘QString&’ from an rvalue of type ‘QString’
    Request(manager, QString(chars[i]), doc, array, list);
```

I also added logging to Request

```
qDebug() << "queryString:" << queryString;
```

and also to AddDataToList

```
void AddDataToList(QVector<QString> &list, QJsonArray &array)
{
    int count = array.count();
    qDebug() << "count:" << count;
    for (int n = 0; n < count; n++)
    {
        QString appendString = array[n].toString();
        qDebug() << "index:" << n << "appendString:" << appendString;
        list.append(appendString);
    }
}
```

Then I started testing. I used shorter array of chars by changing integers to 110 -> 119 which lead to query strings `n,nn, -> vu,vv`. I directed output to a file on each test round so I could analyze the results afterwards.

I got result 2984 over 10 times. During the testing session of about half an hour I got two results that differed. I compared the log files and noticed that sometimes the server returned empty response for some query strings in differing results. The count of result 2984 in parenthesis.

I got result 2816 once:

```
queryString: "nr"
count: 0 (18)
queryString: "ns"
count: 0 (50)
queryString: "nt"
count: 0 (50)
queryString: "nu"
count: 0 (50)
```

I got result 2934 once:

```
queryString: "or"
count: 0 (50)
```

I would say it's a server problem.

**Addition to EDIT part of the question:**

You don't get as detailed error output but anyway it's caught like this:

```
QJsonParseError e;
doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(reply->readAll(), &e);
if ( e.error != QJsonParseError::NoError )
{
    qWarning() << "Json parse error:" << e.errorString().toLatin1().data();
}
```

Here is what I got from parsing:

```
queryString: "uy"
Json parse error: illegal value
count: 0
```

See more details about QJsonParseError Class from [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonparseerror.html).

Note: There is no point of calling QCoreApplication::exec() and entering the main event loop in your current implementation.

Comment: I've added a few more lines at the bottom of my original post.

Comment: `QJsonParseError` is enough as indication. Is your 'Note' about the last line of `int main` function, ie. `return a.exec()`? Qt adds first and last lines in `int main` automatically!  `return 0` works as well in my case. I have no way to avoid `QEventLoop` right?

Comment: actually `int main` does not require a `return` at all!